# Getting notified of a new subscription in NServiceBus

Tags: c#-4.0, nservicebus

Does anyone know of a way that I can get notified of a new subscription occurring for a publisher in NServiceBus? I'd like to run some code every time a new subscription occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Technique 1**

Implementing your own subscription storage would give you access to the client address and messages types they are interested in.

**Technique 2**

```
public void Init()
    {
        IBus bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
           .DefaultBuilder()
           .Log4Net()
           .XmlSerializer()
           .MsmqTransport()
           .DisableRavenInstall()
           .UnicastBus()
           .CreateBus()
           .Start();

        IUnicastBus ubus = bus as IUnicastBus;

        if (null != ubus)
        {
            ubus.ClientSubscribed += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine("Client Subscribed {0}:{1}", e.SubscriberReturnAddress.Machine, e.SubscriberReturnAddress.Queue); };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I guess that would work. I was hoping for a more 'lightweight' solution but if there really is no hook into the subscription messages then I guess that might be my only option.

Comment: Other than implementing your own subscription storage, there really isn't.  I figured this is simpler and also gives you a place to do your processing.

Comment: @RussellTroywest - take a look at option 2, I found an easier way.

Comment: Nice one Adam - Thanks, I was going to look at writing my own sub storage to do it but this is exactly what I was looking for. I only need it to muck about with some spikes at the moment but I'm sure it'll come in handy one day